# Вывод значения как $data['somevalue']

Tags: php, mysql

Есть поле, в котором данные хранятся как `somevalue` set('value1','value2','value3'). Скажите, как сделать запросом аналог

```
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table"));
    $values=array('value1'=>'Значение1','value2'=>'Значение2','value3'=>'значение3');
    echo $values[$data['somevalue']];
```

чтобы можно было вывести значение просто как $data['somevalue'];

Comment: ничего не понятно...

Comment: ну, в базе хранится название значений на англ, а при выводе нужны русские значения

Comment: А можно по больше кода? Что из себя представляет "дата"?

Comment: Или я дурак или что, но у тебя вроде как должно $data['somevalue'] ровняться value1, или любому другому, сделай print_r($data); и покажи результат, так проще

Comment: дата - это массив с запросом

Comment: ну вот, выводит value1, а надо значение1

Comment: Ну это то и по квадратным скобкам понятно, просто самой сути не понятно. Кода слишком мало и не понятно как выглядит эта "дата"

Comment: блин, сделай echo($data['somevalue']);
и скажи что там

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Способ 1, правильный:

```
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `rus_table`.`value1`,`rus_table`.`value2`,`rus_table`.`value3`, FROM table left join rus_table on `table`.`id`=`rus_table`.`id`"));

//rus_table содержит как раз русские значения.
echo $data['somevalue'];
```

Способ 2, простой:

```
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table"));
function my_walk(&$item,$key){
  $values=array('value1'=>'Значение1','value2'=>'Значение2','value3'=>'значение3');
  $item = $values[$item];
}

array_walk($data,'mywalk');

echo $data['somevalue'];
```

Способ 3, только в частном случае небольшого числа полей:

```
Select if(`somevalue`='value1','Значение1',if(`somevalue`='value2','Значение2',if(`somevalue`='value3','Значение3','Значение4'))) as `somevalue` from `table`
```

Comment: дело в том, что надо без отдельной таблицы (там всего 4 вариации поля) и на mysql

Comment: На Mysql - это изврат. Но можно вот так:) *обновил

Comment: cпс, так норм